# Custom XSD for xhtml

Tags: xsd

i trying the following but getting an error

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">   
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" schemaLocation="xhtml.xsd" />

    <xsd:element name="book" type="bookType"/>

    <xsd:complexType name="bookType">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="author" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element ref="xhtml:pre"/>
            <xsd:element ref="xhtml:ul"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

its returning an error on `<xsd:element ref="xhtml:pre"/>`

Comment: Please provide the parser you're using, the error you're getting, the document you're validating, and a list of the things you have tried to resolve the error.

Comment: OK, saying "it's returning ... an error in the schema itself" is progress.  The next step is to read the error message, or at least tell those trying to answer your question what it says.  (Possible cause:  there is no xhtml.xsd in the indicated location.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd" />
```

Instead of your import. It will validate in XML Spy.